# Unable to setup NServiceBus v5 multi-tenant saga example as a hosted service

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, nservicebus

I've looked over the NServiceBus documentation and have run the sample for setting up multiple tenants to keep the saga data in individual databases for each tenant.

https://docs.particular.net/samples/outbox/multi-tenant/?version=core_5

I currently have an NServiceBus application using the **NServiceBus.Host** package and is running as a Windows Service. It is sharing a single saga data table among several tenants so thought it would be simple to convert the sample to be hosted so I could see how I need to proceed to convert my existing project to multi-tenant SQL connections. However, the example uses a console application and a manually created bus.

If I add the **NServiceBus.Host** NuGet package to the sample application an **EndpointConfig.cs** file is added as I expect but I can't figure out how to work with the Pipeline Executor.

In the **Receiver** project in **Program.cs** there is this:

```
internal static PipelineExecutor PipelineExecutor;

var busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
PipelineExecutor = ((UnicastBus) startableBus).Builder.Build<PipelineExecutor>();
```

However, you obviously can't do that inside **EnpointConfig.cs** of a hosted application.

Next if you view **MultiTenantOpenSqlConnectionBehavior.cs** in the **Invoke** method you have access to the context `IncomingContext context` where the individual client connections are stuffed into the context with their corresponding keys and the next pipeline step is executed via `next();`

```
class MultiTenantOpenSqlConnectionBehavior :
    IBehavior<IncomingContext>
{

    public void Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next)
    {
        var defaultConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NServiceBus/Persistence"]
            .ConnectionString;
        #region OpenTenantDatabaseConnection

        string tenant;
        if (!context.PhysicalMessage.Headers.TryGetValue("TenantId", out tenant))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No tenant id");
        }
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[tenant]
            .ConnectionString;
        var lazyConnection = new Lazy<IDbConnection>(() =>
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        });
        var key = $"LazySqlConnection-{defaultConnectionString}";
        context.Set(key, lazyConnection);
        try
        {
            next();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lazyConnection.IsValueCreated)
            {
                lazyConnection.Value.Dispose();
            }
            context.Remove(key);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then in **MultiTenantConnectionProvider.cs**, the static **PipelineExecutor** declared above is referenced and with that context the connection can be retrieved with the same key that was set in the above class.

```
class MultiTenantConnectionProvider :
    DriverConnectionProvider
{

    public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var defaultConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NServiceBus/Persistence"]
            .ConnectionString;

        #region GetConnectionFromContext

        Lazy<IDbConnection> lazy;

        //
        // This line is the problem. The static Program.PipelineExecutor is accessed
        //
        var pipelineExecutor = Program.PipelineExecutor;

        var key = $"LazySqlConnection-{defaultConnectionString}";
        if (
            pipelineExecutor != null &&
            pipelineExecutor.CurrentContext.TryGet(key, out lazy))
        {
            var connection = Driver.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = lazy.Value.ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }
        return base.GetConnection();

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Surely there has to be a way to do this in a hosted application but I can't find any information on how to do this.

Comment: Are you looking to do this on NServiceBus version 5.x?

Comment: Yes, version 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the NServiceBus Host does not support multi tenant scenarios. Instead you can take that sample use a self hosted service https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/windows-service

The code is fairly trivial

Comment: That's a possibility but there's also another issue I have with the sample code that could be a no-go.

I wonder about the thread safety of the static Program.PipelineExecutor.